# About to pass a reference as an argument in a function to alter the value of the argument variable.

Tags: c++, function, reference, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference

I was reading "Beginning C++ Through Game Programming, Fourth Edition" when I found a section about to pass a reference as an argument in a function that says:

"Pass a reference only when you want to alter the value
of the argument variable. However, you should try to avoid changing
argument variables whenever possible."

Basically it says that I shoud avoid to do something like this:

```
void swap(int& x, int& y)
{
    int temp = x;
    x = y;
    y = temp;
}
```

***But, why should I avoid doing this?***

I found very useful to create functions to change variables, because these functions keep my code organized avoiding me to write every variable change in the main() function, and they also avoid me to write the same code repeatedly.

***What alternative is there if I should not do this?***

Comment: _"**But, why should I avoid doing this?**"_ Ask the authors, we probably can't know their intend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the case of swap, pass by reference shoud be used, because *multiple* variables are being changed in the function and the expected behavior of the function is obvious. If you were only changing *one* variable or have a function that should be returning a result, then it is better to return a value for the most part (With some exceptions). For example, supoose you had a function `sum()`:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Usage of this function might be:

```
int x = sum(1, 2); // Obvious and to the point
```

Since there is no need to change any of the variables, one would use pass by value here (Pass by `const` reference doesn't matter here, since POD types are pretty small). If you used pass by reference here, then the function would have changed to:

```
void sum(int a, int b,  int& sum)
{
    sum = a + b;
}
```

Usage of the function above might be:

```
int s;
sum(1, 2, s); // Obscure, unclear
```

Disadvantages of this are that it is unclear what the intent of the function is, and now the result of the function cannot be passed to another function in one line. So pass by reference should only be used when absolutely *necessary*.

On a side note, using a `const` reference for passing large objects to functions is always recommended, since it avoids a copy.